# Sending user specific logs from one host to other using rsyslog

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I am using rsyslog server running on localhost(centos) and remote machine(ubuntu).I am able to send the logs from localhost to remote server using TCP connection and UDP connection able to see the logs in remote server.
My localhost config :

```
 # rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514


#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# File syncing capability is disabled by default. This feature is usually not required,
# not useful and an extreme performance hit
#$ActionFileEnableSync on

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state


#### RULES ####

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure

# Log all the mail messages in one place.
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog


# Log cron stuff
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log




*.* @@192.168.122.50:514
```

My remote server config:

```
      /etc/rsyslog.conf Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#           For more information see
#           /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf


#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514
$AllowedSender TCP, 192.168.0.0/8
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability
$template TmplAuth, "/var/log/client_logs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
$template TmplMsg, "/var/log/client_logs/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"

authpriv.* ?TmplAuth
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none ?TmplMsg

# provides UDP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imudp
#$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 514

# Enable non-kernel facility klog messages
$KLogPermitNonKernelFacility on

###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

authpriv.*                            /var/log/secgw-siglogs;RSYSLOG_FileFormat

$template RemoteStore, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
:source, !isequal, "localhost" -?RemoteStore
:source, isequal, "last" ~$template RemoteStore, "/var/log/remote/%HOSTNAME%/%timegenerated:1:10:date-rfc3339%"
:source, !isequal, "localhost" -?RemoteStore
:source, isequal, "last" ~
```

Now i have to send some user specific logs not all kernel logs,auth logs which are present in /var/log location,Is there any configuration need to be modified ?